Rust C++ binding failing because of subdirectory in my project as a git submodule
I'm trying to build out some binding between Rust and C++ using rust-bindgen because I need to call C++ functions and methods.
Here are the steps, which I followed
Here is the structure:
.
├── Cargo.toml
└── plank
   └── transaction
      ├── build.rs
      ├── Cargo.toml
      ├── couchbase-transactions-cxx // This is C++ code
      │  ├── deps
      │  │  └── couchbase-cxx-client
      │  │     └── core
      │  │        └── cluster.hxx
      │  ├── include
      │  │  └── couchbase
      │  │     └── transactions.hxx // main header file of c++ poject
      │  └── 'other directories and files'
      └── headers.h

I added bindgen in  transaction/Cargo.toml:
[build-dependencies.bindgen]
version = "0.69.4"
default-features = false
features = ["logging", "runtime", "which-rustfmt"]

Here is headers.h entry point for bindgen:
#include "transactions.hxx"

Here is build.rs:
use std::env;
use std::fs::canonicalize;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
// Tell cargo to look for shared libraries in the specified directory
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=/Users/ashi/workspace/couchbase-rs/couchbase-transactions/couchbase-transactions-cxx/");

    // Tell cargo to tell rustc to link the system bzip2
    // shared library.
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=couchbase-transactions-cxx");

    let headers_dir = PathBuf::from("couchbase-transactions-cxx/deps/couchbase-cxx-client/core");
    let headers_dir_canonical = canonicalize(headers_dir).unwrap();
    let include_path = headers_dir_canonical.to_str().unwrap();


    // The bindgen::Builder is the main entry point
    // to bindgen, and lets you build up options for
    // the resulting bindings.
    let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default()
        //.clang_args(&["-I./couchbase-transactions-cxx/include/couchbase"])
        // The input header we would like to generate
        // bindings for.
        .clang_arg("-I./couchbase-transactions-cxx/include/couchbase")
        .clang_arg("-I./couchbase-transactions-cxx/deps/couchbase-cxx-client/core")
        .header("headers.h")
        .clang_arg("-x").clang_arg("c++")
        .clang_arg("-std=c++20")
        //.clang_arg(format!("-I{include_path}"))

        // Tell cargo to invalidate the built crate whenever any of the
        // included header files changed.
        .parse_callbacks(Box::new(bindgen::CargoCallbacks::new()))
        // Finish the builder and generate the bindings.
        .generate()
        // Unwrap the Result and panic on failure.
        .expect("Unable to generate bindings");

    // Write the bindings to the $OUT_DIR/bindings.rs file.
    let out_path = PathBuf::from(env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());
    bindings
        .write_to_file(out_path.join("bindings.rs"))
        .expect("Couldn't write bindings!");
}

While running cargo build, I am getting below error:
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/ashi/workspace/couchbase-rs/target/debug/build/couchbase-transactions-fc01fd053af1b9bb/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-link-search=/Users/ashi/workspace/couchbase-rs/couchbase-transactions/couchbase-transactions-cxx/
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=couchbase-transactions-cxx
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=BINDGEN_EXTRA_CLANG_ARGS_aarch64-apple-darwin
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=BINDGEN_EXTRA_CLANG_ARGS_aarch64_apple_darwin
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=BINDGEN_EXTRA_CLANG_ARGS
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=headers.h

  --- stderr
  ./couchbase-transactions-cxx/include/couchbase/transactions.hxx:23:10: fatal error: 'core/cluster.hxx' file not found
  thread 'main' panicked at couchbase-transactions/build.rs:131:10:
  Unable to generate bindings: ClangDiagnostic("./couchbase-transactions-cxx/include/couchbase/transactions.hxx:23:10: fatal error: 'core/cluster.hxx' file not found\n")
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Try the include dir without core at the end or add a 3rd include dir without the core.

@Markus Great Thanks. This works but it now throws same error for another file in another directory.
After adding clang_arg("-I./couchbase-transactions-cxx/deps/couchbase-cxx-client"), I got another error.
./couchbase-transactions-cxx/deps/couchbase-cxx-client/core/document_id_fmt.hxx:22:10: fatal error: 'fmt/core.h' file not found
If I add corresponding path, I get another error for another file. Is there any way to look sub folders under couchbase-cxx-client automatically?
